# Some Time of Year Rebuses

Tags: rebus

These are probably incredibly easy, but have fun!!

1) [image][image]

[image][image]

2) [image][image][image]

[image][image]

3) [image][image]

[image][image]

4) [image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

[image][image]

5) [image][image][image][image]

[image][image]

6) [image][image][image]

[image][image]

7) [image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: You should format the images smaller so that each rebus appears on its own line.  Or maybe put some horizontal lines between them.  As is, it's kind of hard to tell where one ends and the next begins...

Comment: Added some lines for delineation.  I fear if I make them smaller the first image in #5 would be too small to identify.

Comment: Thank you - I had actually had a lot of trouble figuring out which things belonged to #4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 1. Santa Claus (Sandy + Claws)
>  2. Merry Christmas (Mary + Kris + Mess)
>  3. Mistletoe (Missile + Toe)
>  4. Happy Holidays (cHAP stick + Pee + Holly + Daze)
>  5. Kwanzaa (Kwan + piZZA)
>  6. Menorah (Men + OR + A)
>  7. Fruitcake (Fruit + beefCAKE)

Comment: Well that was fast

Comment: Main reason I created this puzzle?  I felt like this site needed a picture of Brutus Beefcake somewhere on it.